# C# Windows Form App - choose output audio device

Tags: c#, windows, audio, text-to-speech

I'm trying to do some basic app, with System.Speech.Synthesis in c#

It's just a basic form with a text input and after pressing enter it reads the text using ss.SpeakAsync();

The goal is to play that sound on a exact audio output device on Windows but I can't achieve that.

1. I've tried do it by windows settings, App volume and device preferences, but it doesn't work, not sure why.

[image]

I'm setting the correct device, but it plays on the "default" anyways, no matter what I do. It works with any other application correctly (like browser for example) bit with mine it doesn't. It works when I change all system audio to that device, but the main goal is that i want only this app to use "cable input".

2. I've tried to use some 3rd party software to do this (https://github.com/a-sync/audio-router) but it doesn't work either. I set everything, and when I click "play" in my app, then my app crashes with an exception: „[17132] TrayReader.exe” exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

So maybe I'm able to set in the code the correct audio output device? Or how do I fix those previous errors? maybe I need to add some privileges or something? I'm mainly web developer, this is my first time with windows app.

//edit -> it works, when i change all my system audio to cable input, play some sound, and then go back to my main device. It seems like a windows bug?

Answer (score 0):

you may use a 3rd lib Naudio; the example below shows how to return to current position in case the player was playing a song. The key code is player.DeviceNumber = deviceNum; in which deviceNum is 0, 1, 2... depending how many speakers are available in your PC.
A disadvantage of Naudio is that it loads completely the song before playing, and quite slow.

```
        var playback = player.PlaybackState;
        if (playback == PlaybackState.Stopped) // change and exit
        {
            player.DeviceNumber = deviceNum;
            return;
        }
        var currentTime = reader.CurrentTime;
        player.Stop(); // must stop to change output
        player.DeviceNumber = deviceNum;
        player.Init(reader);
        reader.CurrentTime = currentTime;
        if (playback == PlaybackState.Playing)
            player.Play();
```